# Travel planner app/website to plan by attractions/beaches/zoo/amusement park/pubs/Uber

Tags: online-resources, planning, applications

Is there an app which lets me select a destination based on its proximity to certain types of attractions/facilities? For e.g. I would like to search for places which have a zoo, an amusement park, good pubs, beaches and Uber - all within a 50 K.M. radius.

Comment: Walkscore.com?  Might sort of work

Answer (score 1):

**No**, such a service doesn't exist as of 2018. There might be one in the future and I'd personally use it, but unfortunately nothing even comes close yet.